# QAbstractItemModel - inserting rows - how to specify the columns

Tags: c++, qt

The [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#details) shows a table

[image: Table Model]

But the API does not allow you to specify the column under which to insert the rows.

[`void QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows(const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows)

[image]

Under which column does the row get inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always insert a complete row, not a single cell so when adding a row into a table model the parent is the root index (= invalid QModelIndex), if you insert into a tree then the parent is the parent node.